# Ordenar por el mayor año

Tags: group-by

necesito saber que estoy haciendo mal.
Tengo que sacar el total de ventas del año 2014 donde la fecha de pago es a 30 dias. Esto es lo que tengo.

```
   SELECT MAX(fecha_orden), cantidad = COUNT(*)
   FROM ventas
   WHERE forma_pago = '30 días'
   GROUP BY fecha_orden
```

No me agrupa por el mayor año, sino que me aparecen todos.

Comment: Si, tengo que sacar el total de ventas del año 2014, donde la la forma de pago es 30 dias

Comment: Intenta algo así: `SELECT  COUNT(*) AS cantidad FROM ventas WHERE forma_pago = '30 días' AND YEAR(fecha_orden)=2014 GROUP BY fecha_orden` Tienes que filtrar por el año, usando la función `YEAR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
SELECT MAX(fecha_orden) as fo, cantidad    = COUNT(*) FROM ventas WHERE    forma_pago = '30 días' GROUP BY    fo
```

Answer (score 0):

para hacer la suma tienes que ocupar el sum por ejemplo:

```
SELECT sum(total_venta) from ventas
```

Y para que te aparezca el total de ventas del año 2014 donde la fecha de pago es a 30 días podría ser con dos condiciones:

```
SELECT sum(total_venta) from ventas WHERE 
YEAR(fecha_orden) = 2014 AND fecha_pago = '30 dias'
GROUP BY fecha_orden
```

**Recuerda como consejo no ocupar ni ñ ni acentos para no tener problemas con las queries.**